# error PHP-LARAVEL Undefined variable:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc

estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel. Pero me tira el siguiente error.

En mi controller tengo esto:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $lanifComercial = new PlanifComercial();
    $lanifComercial->LABORATORIO = 'LABORATORIO';
   return view('Planif_Comercial.Edit',$lanifComercial);
}
```

y en mi view tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me tira el siguiente error :

> (2/2) ErrorException  Undefined variable: lanifComercial (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaz-carga-soap\resources\views\Planif_Comercial\Edit.blade.php)

Desde ya agradezco sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza un array o un compact para pasar los datos a la vista:

```
return view('mi-vista', compact('lanifComercial');
```

El array:

```
return view('mi-vista', ['lanifComercial' => $lanifComercial]
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con que no la reconoce?

Comment: Perdon, reformulo.
Como obtengo el valor de la 'LABORATORIO'' en la view ??
desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes, lo harías así: `$lanifComercial->LABORATORIO`, sin embargo te recomiendo que la definas y utilices en minúsculas, busca en Google "camel case"

Comment: Haaa ya lo encontre, mil perdones.

era asi $lanifComercial ->LABORATORIO

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.